# Spring Boot Thymeleaf email template inline image

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use an inline image in my thymeleaf template. Followed by this manual http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

For unknown reason image is not sent, i also didn't get any errors.

**in template:**

```
 <img src="image_name.png" th:src="|cid:${imageResourceName}|"/>
```

**sending email:**

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Autowired
private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

@Value(value = "classpath:templates/mails/listing/images/img11.png")
private Resource logoImageResource;

public boolean sendRichEmail(String receipient, EmailType emailType) {
    EmailMessageConstructor emailMessageConstructor = new EmailMessageConstructor(emailType);

    String recipientAddress = receipient;
    String subject = emailMessageConstructor.getEmailTopic();
    String from = "no-reply@xxx.com";

    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = null;
    try {
        helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "utf-8");

        final Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariable("name", "User1");
        ctx.setVariable("dateNow", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("dateExpired", MyUtils.addDays(new Date(), 30));

        final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process(emailMessageConstructor.getEmailTemplate(), ctx);
        mimeMessage.setContent(htmlContent, "text/html");

        // Add the inline image, referenced from the HTML code as "cid:${imageResourceName}"
        try {
            String imageResourceName = logoImageResource.getFilename();
            String imageContentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(logoImageResource.getFile());
            final InputStreamSource imageSource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(logoImageResource.getInputStream()));
            helper.addInline(imageResourceName, imageSource, imageContentType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        helper.setTo(new InternetAddress(recipientAddress));
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        try {
            helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "xxx"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        logger.error("Message creation exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Want to use the image located in

```
/resources/templates/mails/listing/images/img11.png
```

Comment: Is this code running locally or on a web server while you are trying the email functionality? Also, make sure accessing the image resource does not require authentication.

Comment: locally.
doesn't require, sure.

Comment: is it working for you now? I am also facing the same  issue.

Comment: sry don't have that source code now. i remember that it was fixed, but don't remember how.